# Working with getenv_s in C to process CONTENT_LENGTH

Tags: c, security, buffer, overflow

Being new to C, I just came across the C11 addition getenv_s. Here is what I'm actually trying to do:

[Handling POST data sent by html form in CGI C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50752374/handling-post-data-sent-by-html-form-in-cgi-c)

I'm trying to sanitize, both CONTENT_LENGTH and message-body(stdin) in my case. That is the objective here.

So in order to limit the upper-bounds (against malformed CONTENT_LENGTH, trying to cause overflow), I tried using an array instead of pointer, like this:

```
char some[512];
some = getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH");
```

It naturally threw an error (incompatible types when assigning to type char[512] from type char *). So I assume,

Q1. getenv is already a string?

Then I came across "getenv_s"
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/getenv

Q2. Can anyone tell me a safe-as-rocksolid way of using this? To avoid underflow, overflow, etc.

Comment: getenv["CONTENT_LENGTH"] -- What is this???

Comment: Sorry, was in a hurry (had to step away for a bit), thus the mistake. If you see the linked question, I had the right syntax there. Anyways fixed. Thanks.

Comment: char *some = getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH");

Comment: Well, that is not helpful. I'm playing with data types here, hence I didn't use a single line. Besides, this question is not related to that, but instead getenv_s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, do not use any of the `_s` functions.  They are an *optional* feature of C11 which, to my knowledge, has never been fully implemented by anyone, not even Microsoft, which invented them, and it has been proposed to remove them again; even more importantly, they do not actually solve the problems they purport to address.  (The intention was to have a bunch of drop-in replacements for dangerous string-related functions, but it turns out that that doesn't work; fixing string-related security bugs in C programs requires actual redesign with thought put into it.  The functions that genuinely could not be used safely already had portable replacements, e.g. `fgets` instead of `gets`, `snprintf` instead of `sprintf`, `strsep` instead of `strtok` -- sometimes the replacement is not in ISO C but it's usually widespread enough not to worry about, or you can get a shim implementation from [gnulib](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/).)

`getenv` is guaranteed to return a valid NUL-terminated C string (or a null pointer), but the string could be arbitrarily long.  In the context of a CGI program written in C, the correct way to "sanitize" the value of the `CONTENT_LENGTH` environment variable is to feed it to `strtol` and carefully check for errors:

```
/* Returns a valid content_length, or -1 on error.  */
long get_content_length(void)
{
    char *content_length, *endp;
    long rv;

    content_length = getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH");
    if (!content_length) return -1;
    errno = 0;
    rv = strtol(content_length, &endp, 10);
    if (endp == content_length || *endp || errno || rv <= 0)
        return -1;
    return rv;
}
```

Each of the four clauses in the `if` statement after the `strtol` call checks for a different class of ill-formed input.  You have to clear `errno` explicitly before the call, because the value `strtol` returns when it reports an overflow is also a value it can return when there was no overflow, so the only way to distinguish is to look at `errno`, but `errno` could have a stale nonzero value from some earlier operation.

Note that even if `CONTENT_LENGTH` is syntactically valid, it might not be *trustworthy*.  That is, the actual amount of POST data available to you might be either less or more than `CONTENT_LENGTH`.  Make sure to pay attention to the numbers returned by `read` as well.  (This is an example of how swapping out string functions for "hardened" ones doesn't solve all your problems.)

Comment: I don't know about other _s functions, but I have already seen getenv_s being used in the book "ModernC(by Jens Gustedt)" as well as "C in a Nutshell (by Peter Prinz)", where they actually recommend it instead of getenv. Portability is not a issue here, in-case that is what you are worried about. I only intend to run it on a single server with latest GCC. I also found this post on windows: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tb2sfw2z.aspx

Comment: Even after using fgets in my current script, should I still be worried about reading more than or less than CONTENT_LENGTH? And what if, CONTENT_LENGTH contains dangerous input? The only way I can think of logically is to accept only 1 to X (numerical/integer) value of CONTENT_LENGTH, and else throw an error page.

Comment: @AhmadBilal Yes, you do still have to worry about there being more or less data available than CONTENT_LENGTH says.  fgets will not return more data than you tell it to read _in one call_, but if you're assuming that CONTENT_LENGTH bytes are always immediately followed by an EOF you could be in trouble.  "Accept only 1 to X value of CONTENT_LENGTH" is exactly what the above function does.

Comment: I'm looking at it, and trying a few things on my own as well. I will reply back here tomorrow. Thanks for your contribution btw.

Comment: Can you please add a answer that uses getenv_s as well?

Comment: As it should not be used, I decline to do that.

Comment: What is your opinion on strnlen (note, not strlen)? in regards to string length safety discussed above ?

Comment: @AhmadBilal I don't understand how strnlen would be useful in this context, but this is probably because I don't have a clear enough picture of what you are thinking of doing with it. Please ask a new question about that.

Comment: @AhmadBilal Note however that POST data can be arbitrary binary data, so treating it as a C string is definitely the wrong approach.